# Python Web scraping- Required Libraries and how to do it

Tags: python-2.7

I am looking for some real help. I want to web scraping using Python, I need it because i want to import some database, How can we do that in Python. What libraries do we need ?

Answer (score 0):

The most popular library i know is this:
[scrapy](http://scrapy.org/)

It has a very good documentation, and useful examples to start with.
And with some google search i think you can find a way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
1) Beautiful Soup
2) Python Requests
3) Scrapy
4) Mechanize
... and many more. These are the most popular tools, and easy to learn for the beginner. 
From there, you can branch out to more complex stuff such as UserAgentSpoofing, HTML Load balancing, Regex, XPATH and CSS Selectors. You will need these to scrape more difficult sites that has protection or login fields.

Hope that helps. 
Cheers

Comment: Hi Mig Yu,
Thanks a lot for your response. I would like to know whether all these libraries work on windows platform.

Comment: hey. of course. I use them on windows. However, i would strongly recommend you using some virtual environment like virtualenv. Because your python versions will most likely get mixed up. EG: Scrapy only works on python2. BeautifulSoup works on Python3. You will need to use your python versions interchangeably.

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanya great to hear that. if you have any other problems, do comment here. I can try to help. btw, if my answer is useful appreciate you can upvote it. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested I too would use Beautiful Soup and Python Requests, but if you get problems with websites which have to load some data with Javascript after the page has loaded and you only get the incomplete html with Request, try using Selenium and PhantomJs for the scraping.